# How to import a variable from LUA to xml?

Tags: xml, lua

I need a generic xml file for different model devices. The element  is variable depending on different models but everything else in xml is same for all models. The model name is defined in LUA file. Is there any way to import this model name from LUA to xml file?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to process that XML file to add that model name to it. You may be able to do it from the same Lua file where the model name is "defined" using these steps:

- read the XML file (`local text = io.open("filename"):read('*a')`),
- modify the file to include the model name; if you mark the location with something like `MODELNAME`, you can then replace with with the actual model using `gsub`: `text:gsub('MODELNAME', modelname)`
- write the updated content back: `io.open("filename", "w"):write(text)`.

Comment: Thank you, Paul. I should have stated more clearly. The model name is not really defined in LUA file but is assigned in LUA file at run time, while the xml file has to be retrieved before LUA file executes. I guess there is no solution for the problem perhaps.